# oauth2 for service account

Tags: google-apps-script, google-oauth, google-calendar-api, service-accounts

I want to have a Google API Script deployed as a web app.  I understand how to do that.

I want this script to list and add events on a Google Calendar.  I have plenty of documentation and examples to do that.

I want this script to read a calendar using a service account.  I have already created the service account and shared the calendar with it.

The end goal is to have a Javascript client access this script, use it to retrieve a list of events on the calendar and use it to create events on it.

What I don't understand is how to authenticate a service account.  I keep seeing code like:

```
  oauthConfig.setConsumerKey("anonymous");
  oauthConfig.setConsumerSecret("anonymous");
  oauthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl(
         "https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
  oauthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://accounts.google.com/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
  oauthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
```

How do I modify this to use a service account? I do not understand if/how I pass in the service account client id/email address.  I also am unclear how to pass in the public/private keys.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct setup for accessing a GSheet published as a webapp via a service account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60142762/correct-setup-for-accessing-a-gsheet-published-as-a-webapp-via-a-service-account)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Drive API documentation has a really good example on how to use service account. It has steps by steps on how to create a service account, and it also includes multiple code samples.  The only thing is you would have to change the scope to Calendar API from Drive API.

https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation

Comment: is Google Apps Admin Console an absolute requirement?

Comment: For allowing 2 legged OAuth, yes it is. :(

Comment: BUT if you are going to publish it as marketplace apps, it should be installed for your user automatically in Admin Console as they are going through the installation process.

Comment: I need a solution independent of Google Apps Admin Console.  All I want to do is allow anyone to read/add events to a Google Calendar.  I restrict access to the Calendar via some Javascript that only allows read/add.  The only other restriction is I don't' want anyone to have to enter a userid/password.  The Calendar being accessed is mine - I want people to read/add to it without having to enter any kind of userid/password.  I've been told Service Accounts is the best way accomplish this.  Is that correct?  Do you know anything about Oauth2 authentication via Google App Engine?