# Correct setup for accessing a GSheet published as a webapp via a service account

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications, google-oauth, service-accounts

I have a GSheet published as a webapp and I am trying to allow access to it from a service account

- It is set to allow access to Anyone.
- I can access it when i hit the
  deployed app URL directly.
- I have converted the project to be GCP
  standard project.
- I created a Service Account attached to the
  project.
- Service account has editor access.
- I then also granted access to
  the sheet to the service account.

Trying to access it using the following python code and getting a 401.
Following examples [here](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html)

```
from __future__ import print_function
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.auth.transport.urllib3 import AuthorizedHttp

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
'service_account.json', scopes=SCOPES)


def main():
    try:
        authed_http = AuthorizedHttp(credentials)

        response = authed_http.request(
           'GET',   'https://script.google.com/a/<DOMAIN_NAME_REDACTED>/macros/s/AKfycbwv53GaXRCvjQMYizjqI4PsLeNMAcmCtHjRhZE9AlheIp0qE_s/exec')
    print(response)
except BaseException as err_base2:
    print(err_base2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I think I am missing something obvious.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to access to Web Apps which was deployed as `Execute the app as: Me` and `Who has access to the app: Anyone` using `request` of python.
- The Google Apps Script project deploying Web Apps has already shared with the service account.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? In this case, please modify the scope as follows.

#### From:

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
```

#### To:

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
```

and/or

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly']
```

- Even when your script of Web Apps uses the methods of Spreadsheet, it seems that the scope of Drive API is required.

#### Note:

- In this case, you can retrieve the returned values from Web Apps with `print(response._body)` in your script.

If this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and got "We&#39;re sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again". Scopes now look like. SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly']

Comment: @Simon Taylor Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In my environment, I could confirm that both above modification and your scopes worked. And unfortunately, I cannot understand about the detail information of your Web Apps from your question. So in order to correctly understand about it, can you provide the sample Google Apps Script and the detail settings of your Web Apps for replicating your current issue? If you can do, please add it to your question. By this, I would like to check it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: @Simon Taylor By the way, when you modified the script of Web Apps, please redeploy Web Apps as new version. Also please be careful this.

Comment: I can see that the scope change has overcome the permissions issue. I can see i have another problem now. Will raise a seperate question on this one. Thanks for your help once again!

Comment: @Simon Taylor Thank you for replying. Also I would like to check your new question.