# "Login with" experience when only service account can be used?

Tags: google-oauth, databricks

We're building a web app where a user is able to work with their BigQuery data.
We'd like to offer users an easy and quick experience when making the connection (i.e "login with google"), so using the web app OAUTH flow seems like the way to go.

However, it seems like our app only knows how to handle service account credentials.
The app is based (server side) on Databricks, which means Spark will be used to make the connection. As far as we could find - Spark only accepts service accounts.

Has anyone had similar challenge and can share their experience?

We have an idea to use the access token from the web app flow to create a service account programmatically but it sounds a bit hackie.

Searching SO I found this old post:
[oauth2 for service account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21648412/oauth2-for-service-account)

The idea is similar but I'm sure people gathered more experience with this.

Comment: you can't use a service account for your usecase its only intended for accounts you the developer control.   Switch to Web authorization